# Redirect in an Axios DELETE request promise uses DELETE instead of GET

Tags: javascript, axios

I expect to be able to use a `window.location = '/'` in an `.then` callback that uses `GET` instead of `DELETE` when the original request is a `DELETE`.

Here's what I mean:

```
axios.delete('/logoff')
   .then(() => {
     window.location = '/signin';
   })
```

You'd think after the successful `DELETE` request, that the request to be redirected to `/signin` would be performed as a `GET` - however the it's performed as a `DELETE` as if the option is sticky.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was in my server side authentication system and not on the client side.

I don't think this will be a problem for anyone *not* using Devise for Rails alongside a client side AJAX based sign out call.

My solution was to modify devise's configuration to use `GET` instead of `DELETE` requests for signing off:

```
  # config/initializers/devise.rb
  ...
  # The default HTTP method used to sign out a resource. Default is :delete.
  config.sign_out_via = :get # this was changed from :delete to :get
```

Now my client side sign out call correctly redirects to the sign in page because the signout HTTP method and the signin HTTP method are both `GET`.

Comment: I would not recommend using GET for signout. This might be due to the signout route being overridden in the routes file. It would be helpful if you post the concerned routes.

Comment: It's the default configuration for mounting a route in the devise documentation. It must be an issue within the devise routing itself and this question is probably better posed on their Github as an issue rather than here.

Answer (score 0):

You should return status code 303 to say browser you want to redirect to other page.

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 303 See Other redirect status
> response code indicates that the redirects don't link to the newly
> uploaded resources, but to another page (such as a confirmation page
> or an upload progress page). This response code is usually sent back
> as a result of PUT or POST. The method used to display this redirected
> page is always GET

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/303